# Searching for installed games with Node Webkit

Tags: javascript, webkit, node-webkit

Is there a way you can think of searching for installed games? I'm trying to figure out how to do this with JS but I can't.

Thanks!

Comment: js doens´t and shouldn´t have access to computer installed programs

Comment: I agree with that, but using Node Webkit?